# Why my SVF aws link is not working but the link provided by Autodesk is working?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Okay so I used this code for the viewer

```js
//viewer.js
var MODEL_URLS = [
  // "https://petrbroz.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/svf-samples/sports-car/0.svf",
  "https://bray-transformation-img.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/downloaded_svf/0.svf",
];
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ env: "Local" }, async function () {
  const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById("preview"));
  for (const url of MODEL_URLS) {
    viewer.start(url);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.css"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <script
      language="JavaScript"
      src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v7.*"
    ></script>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
      }
      #preview {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Autodesk Forge: Local SVF</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="preview"></div>
    <script src="scripts/viewer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And if I use this link for **0.svf**:
https://petrbroz.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/svf-samples/sports-car/0.svf
Then viewer is working.

---

But when I use my own link for same from aws:
https://bray-transformation-img.s3.ap-south1.amazonaws.com/downloaded_svf/0.svf

The viewer is giving me an error as:
[image]

---

So is there any configuration to host a svf file in s3 so that it will work?

Answer (score 0):

The **.svf* file is just a manifest that typically references other files (with geometry data, textures, camera information, property metadata, etc.) using relative file paths. All these files must be uploaded and served together with the SVF file itself.

In your screenshot you can see that after the viewer loads the *0.svf* file, it is then looking for another file called *CameraDefinitions.bin*, and that file is probably missing in your S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Right I got the answer now and also the API for the translation of svf file to get the whole bundle of the file.